# How to change the column headers in quicksight programatically?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have multiple reports to publish in quicksight. Each report is getting generated from a different dataset that i have added to the dashboard. In total there are 10 datasets so there are going to be 10 reports. Most of these reports have a lot of repeated column headers. Is there a way to change the name of the column headers programmatically so that I can copy it for all the other reports ?

Below is an example of the columns in the datasets. The real dataset is pretty heavy so cannot share here.

```
Dataset 1 - 
      user_id, user_name, user_country, user_city, number_of_jobs_finished

Dataset 2 - 
      user_id, user_name, user_country, user_city, number_of_interactions
.
.
.
Dataset 10 - 
      user_id, user_name, user_country, user_city, number_of_movies_watched
```

-Thanks,
Vinit

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CLI

- Use the [Dataset CLI / API](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/quicksight/create-data-set.html)

  CustomSql -> (structure)

  ```
  A physical table type built from the results of the custom SQL query.
  ```

  DataSourceArn -> (string)

  ```
   The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the data source.
  ```

  Name -> (string)

  ```
   A display name for the SQL query result.
  ```